# Getting error when parsing JSON string which includes double quotes

Tags: c#, jackson

I am trying to sent username as raj"gogetter"mclean using JSON but getting below error:

```
{"$errorDump":"org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException:Unexpected character ('g' (code 103)):was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries\n at     [Source: com.softwareag.is.enterprisegateway.net.HttpInputStream@3b2827cd;
```

I am using string format like below:

```
Utility.GetGlobalSSOWebMethod("POST", uri, ref statusCode, @"{""username"": """ + userName + @""",""password"":""" + password + @""",""country"":""" + this.CountryCode + @""",""redirect"":""" + redirectApplicationUrl + @"""}");
```

This is the json object which is causing an error:

[image: json object]

I tried looking to few questions posted here but not the exact issue happened.Also please suggest how to use Json serializer instead of string concatenations.

Comment: That's not valid JSON - how are you generating it?

Comment: I suppose you generated this JSON using string concatenation operations rather than using a JSON serializer. The result of this concatenation is the invalid string you ended up with.

Comment: @Darin yes its string concatenation. How to overcome this?. because sometimes users creates usernames with different special characters. How to handle?

Comment: @rajkumar, by using a JSON serializer to generate the JSON.

Comment: not a valid JSON. Please Use JSONSerializer that is inbuilt in VS or use JSON.NET library from Nuget !

Comment: @Darin,@Apoorv thanks for suggestion, i will look into it

Answer (score 1):

You might need to escape quotes (\" instead of ") if you are embedding a string in a JSON string. An example could be that you are trying to embed some HTML into a JSON string, and this HTML contains quotes and all these fabulous things which break the serialization.